# qt widget for scrolled window enabling to port ouput of terminal

Tags: qt, widget, output

I am new to Qt and was wondering if there was a widget which could enable one to port the output of the terminal to a scrolled window like widget. Basically I am wanting it to use it in a plasmoid. can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily create an auto-scrolling list by using a [QListWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#details) and offering a function which calls [scrollToBottom()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#scrollToBottom) whenever you add a message.

Comment: thanx a lot exactly what i wanted!